# JWT token in Blazor App Page needs to be loaded twice to validate token

Tags: azure, jwt, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server application with JWT authentication. The application authenticates using a JWT token in the URL. The applications runs successfully in debug mode under localhost locally without any issues.

When published the application to Azure service the following happens:

1. Go to google or any website
2. Paste url with token
3. It doesn’t validate the token and redirects to the error razor page
4. Paste same url again and it works completely fine and loads correctly

As it’s not happening in debug mode on visual studio not sure on the best way to debug this? Or why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

You could have an issue with CORS? Does it work if you go through the normal authentication flow on the app? E.g., using incognito browser, open Azure app, you are unauthenticated so you get redirected to login, after login you get redirected to app again?

If that works, you are having issues with where the request is coming from (possibly). There really isn't much info to work with here - can you update with browser Developer Tools console output/network tab and then the server logs?